# PHP order by value of array key

Tags: php

I have an array being created which contains a date:

```
$arr = array();
$arr["one"][] = array(
    'due' => '17-01-2021 10:00:00',
);
$arr["one"][] = array(
    'due' => '17-01-2021 09:00:00',
);
$arr["two"][] = array(
    'due' => '19-01-2021 09:00:00',
);
$arr["two"][] = array(
    'due' => '18-01-2021 09:00:00',
);
```

And I want to order by the value of the 'due' key

I tried adding this uasort function:

```
uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a["due"] <=> $b["due"];
});

print_r($arr);
```

But that still shows in the order above, whereas it should be showing the '09:00:00' value first

Comment: I'm not aware of any way you can do this using the `uasort` function, surely it'd be easier for you to create a loop, or is this an issue for performance?

Comment: A couple of issues - your data is in `$arr["one"]`, so use this as the array to sort, and both sides of your test are `$b["due"]`

Comment: @NigelRen I do have more keys than just "one", so i used `$ret`

Comment: If your data is more complex than this, then you would need to show a short example to clarify this, but hopefully the idea may help.

Comment: @NigelRen see updated example

Comment: One thing to be very careful of is that you are comparing strings and (it sounds as though) you want it in date/time order.

Comment: that is correct, however I could change it to a datetime inside the `uasort` ?

Comment: Do you want to have each index sorted individually? e.g. `$arr['one']` should be sorted ascending and `$arr['two']` as well?

Comment: no, just the "due" key, it can ignore the first keys

Comment: That doesn't really make sense: You have two individual arrays here, sorting them "together" would only make sense if you expect one final array.

Comment: @charlie I would have answers for both cases: 1) one final array, 2) each index (one, two..) sorted individually based on the due key. If you let me know which one is the case you are looking for I'm happy to post an answer.

Comment: ah, sorry im having a blank moment. i use each index separately, but yes sorted individually would work best for me

Comment: @charlie What is the expected output? Please update your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach wasn't really that far off, I basically just changed a few little things:

1. Loop over each "word-number-indexed" array individually (those indexed under `one` and `two` in the main array `$arr`).
2. Convert the due dates/times to unix timestamps to have an integer that can be compared. Without this, PHP tries to sort the strings on a character-by-character basis which does not work with your format but would work if your format was `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` (because the "biggest" position value would be at the start).
3. Use `usort` instead of `uasort` since there is no point in keeping the keys (which are integers to begin with and neither `one` nor `due` in this context.

```php
$arr = array();
$arr["one"][] = array(
    'due' => '17-01-2021 10:00:00',
);
$arr["one"][] = array(
    'due' => '17-01-2021 09:00:00',
);
$arr["two"][] = array(
    'due' => '19-01-2021 09:00:00',
);
$arr["two"][] = array(
    'due' => '18-01-2021 09:00:00',
);


foreach ($arr as &$numberIndex) {
    usort($numberIndex, function ($a, $b) {
        return strtotime($a["due"]) <=> strtotime($b["due"]);
    });
}

print_r($arr);
```

Some side notes:

- Note the `&` at `&$numberIndex`, without this PHP works on an in-place copy of your value and it is never changed in `$arr`.
- This approach with `strototime()` only works if all your dates/times are after epoch time 0 (which is 1st of January 1970). If you need to use older dates you can create `DateTime()` objects within the sort callback.

The resulting array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [one] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [due] => 17-01-2021 09:00:00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [due] => 17-01-2021 10:00:00
                )

        )

    [two] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [due] => 18-01-2021 09:00:00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [due] => 19-01-2021 09:00:00
                )

        )

)
```